# Rails ActiveRecord select usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, activerecord

I've been confused for a while, I follow the [rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields), and it say

`Client.select("viewable_by, locked")` will only select only a subset of fields.

Now I got a model call `Goods`

```
class Goods < ActiveRecord::Base {
               :id => :integer,
             :name => :string,
    :translate_key => :string,
       :created_at => :datetime,
       :updated_at => :datetime,
    :discount_json => :text,
    :price_mapping => :text,
       :goods_type => :string,
     :reference_id => :integer,
        :available => :boolean
}
```

When I try `Goods.select(:name)`, it works fine.
However, when I did

```
Goods.select(:name,:translate_key)
```

It threw `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple columns pass them in an array

```
Goods.select([:name, :translate_key])
```

This way you can still use symbols

Active record [select](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Goods.select("name,translate_key")
```

Reference: [Active Recor Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the little dot.